# the result does not fit in the variable long

Tags: variables, arduino, long-integer, unsigned

I use my Arduino and my problem is that the result of 60*1000 is wrong.
I tried to store this in long and int - result is -5536.
in unsigned long the result is 4294961760. What's the problem?
The answer for this question will help me during working on a bigger project.

```
    void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  delay(1000);
}


void loop()
{  
  unsigned long czas=60*1000;
  Serial.println(czas);
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: You are getting an overflow because it probably thinks 60 and 100 are `int`s, and on the platform (atmega) `int`s are only two bytes, whose limit is well under 60000. Cast them before multiplying.

Comment: as you can see, I use unsigned long here, which is a lot bigger than 6 000. The result is still inproper.

Comment: it's not what's on the left hand side, it's what's implicitly on the right hand side. It does the arithmetic, all the while maintaining `int`s, becomes 60000, which overflows 16bit ints. THEN it casts the result into the left hand side datatype.